# Grafana HTTP Error Bad Gateway and Templating init failed errors

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, grafana, prometheus, minikube

Use `helm` installed `Prometheus` and `Grafana` on `minikube` at local.

```
$ helm install stable/prometheus
$ helm install stable/grafana
```

Prometheus server, alertmanager grafana can run after set port-forward:

```
$ export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app=prometheus,component=server" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
$ kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 9090

$ export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app=prometheus,component=alertmanager" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
$ kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 9093

$ export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app=excited-crocodile-grafana,component=grafana" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
$ kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 3000
```

[image]
[image]

Add Data Source from grafana, got `HTTP Error Bad Gateway` error:

[image]

Import dashboard 315 from:

> https://grafana.com/dashboards/315

Then check `Kubernetes cluster monitoring (via Prometheus)`, got `Templating init failed` error:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the HTTP settings of Grafana you set `Access` to `Proxy`, which means that Grafana wants to access Prometheus. Since Kubernetes uses an overlay network, it is a different IP.

There are two ways of solving this:

1. Set `Access` to `Direct`, so the browser directly connects to Prometheus.
2. Use the Kubernetes-internal IP or domain name. I don't know about the Prometheus Helm-chart, but assuming there is a `Service` named `prometheus`, something like `http://prometheus:9090` should work.

Comment: In my grafana  Dashboard the Node metrics( CPU , memory and Network) are not getting loaded. I installed Grafana and Prometheus using helm charts.

Comment: amaizing! thanks, this solution just solved my error using Kubernetes + Prometheus + Grafana.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off the firewall on appliance, post that adding http://prometheus:9090 on URL did not throw bad gateway error.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to find a "proper" fix, but I found a workaround:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: k8s
  name: prometheus-k8s
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app: prometheus
    prometheus: k8s
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  clusterIP: None
```

By setting the `clusterIP` to `None`, the service changes to "Headless" mode, which means that requests are sent directly to a random one of the pods in that service/cluster. More info here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services

There's probably a better solution, but this is the only one I've found that actually works for me, with [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus). (I've tried docker-desktop, k3d, and kind, and all of them have the same issue, so I doubt it's the emulator's fault; and I stripped my config down to basically just kube-prometheus, so it's hard to understand where the problem lies, but oh well.)